# Question about the roots of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

if two real Polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ of degree $m\ge2$ and $n\ge1$ respectively satisfy-
$f\left(x^2+1\right)=f(x)g(x)$ for every $x \in R$, then

1. $f$ has exactly one real root $x_0$ such that $f^\prime(x_0)\ne0$
2. $f$ has exactly one real root  $x_0$ such that $f^\prime(x_0)=0$
3. $f$ has $m$ distinct real roots
4. $f$ has no real root

Please explain in detail.

Comment: `please explain in detail` You go first. Please explain in detail what you have tried to attempt to solve it, and where you got stuck.

Comment: Also you can mention what you know about characterizing the roots of polynomials. For example, what role the determinant and the derivative play.

Comment: I think this is more of a baby challenge problem rather than a standard HW problem (depending on the level of the course), so I'm inclined to post a solution. Should I hold off?

Comment: This is yet another example of what I call "a drive-by question". The OP posts a question, then disconnects, avoiding any interaction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ has a real root, let $a$ be a root of $f$ with largest absolute value.

By hypothesis, $f(a)=0$ implies $f(a^2+1) = 0$, hence by choice of $a$,

\begin{align*}
&|a^2 + 1| \le |a|\\[4pt]
\implies\; &(a^2+1)^2 \le a^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^4 + 2a^2 + 1 \le a^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^4 + a^2 + 1 \le 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

contradiction.

Therefore $f$ has no real roots.